# Ссылки на группу ВК, возвращаемые функцией VK API wall.get в поле text

Tags: django, вконтакте

Добрый день.

В django, при попытке прочитать последние записи на стене группы ВКонтакте, функция `wall.get` возвращает текст записи в поле `text`. При этом, если в теле поста присутствует сслылка на группу ВК, то возвращаемый текст содержит в квадратных скобках id группы и ее название, разделенные вертикальной чертой. Например:

```
 _'text':'[clubXXXXXXX|Название группы]Текст записи на стене'_.
```

Все это выводится на страницу. Как победить такое поведение?

Comment: Я не специалист по питону, но в java можно взять к примеру по нужному символу индекс его позиции в строке, в вашем случае это два символа "[" и "]"   ->> index1 = yourText.indexOf("[") и index2 = yourText.indexOf("]") таким образом вы получите индексы символов между которыми текст который вам не нужен, после этого можете создать новую строку из исходной типа text = yourText.subString(index2, yourText.lenght) где index2 - это место с которого начинается текст записи и yourText.lenght длина исходного текста, это число будет значением индекса последнего элемента.

Comment: Ну тут дело в том, что название группы именно **должно** присутствовать в контексте записи на стене. Пример: "Друзья, сегодня в группе НазваниеГруппы проводится голосование, в котором мы предлагаем вам принять участие". НазваниеГруппы оформлено в виде ссылки и при попытке прочесть этот пост функцией wall.get возвращаемое значение содержит: 'text':'Друзья, сегодня в группе [clubXXXXXXX|НазваниеГруппы] проводится голосование, в котором мы предлагаем вам принять участие'. Думаю, что это поведение можно как-то подавить или обойти. Но не знаю как.

Answer (score 1):

Сделал запрос в техподдержку разработчиков ВКонтакта, ответ - только обрабатывать строки заключенные в квадратные скобки и делать замену.
Если кому то нужно даю код:

```
# Если в тексте записи на стене ВКонтакте встречается ссылка на
# группу ВКонтакте, то ссылка возвращается в виде [clubXXXXXXXX|Название группы]
# pattern_link находит все такие подстроки в записи на стене.
# pattern_group выделяет из соответствующего pattern_link текста подстроку между | и ]
# после чего происходит замена подстроки
# Параметры:
#     текст записи на стене
def replace_link_with_group(record):
    # Построка в квадратных скобках,начинающаяся с club и имеющая разделитель |
    pattern_link = re.compile(ur'(\[club[^\[\]]+\])', re.UNICODE) 

    # Подстрока между | закрывающей квадратной скобкой
    pattern_group = re.compile(ur'\|([^\[\]]+)\]', re.UNICODE)

    to_replace = re.findall(pattern_link, record['text'])
    message = record['text']
    for pos in to_replace:
        replace_by = re.findall(pattern_group, pos)
        message = message.replace(pos, replace_by[0])

    return message
```

Работает на django 1.9